# Dealing with problematic parent-child relationships enforced by C FFI

Tags: rust, ffi, lifetime

I have a C library with an interface similar to this: (I have represented the C API within Rust, so that all of the code in this question can be concatenated in a single `.rs` file and easily tested)

```
// Opaque handles to C structs
struct c_A {}
struct c_B {}

// These 2 `create` functions allocate some heap memory and other 
// resources, so I have represented this using Boxes.
extern "C" fn create_a() -> *mut c_A {
    let a = Box::new(c_A {});
    Box::into_raw(a)
}

// This C FFI function frees some memory and other resources, 
// so I have emulated that here.
extern "C" fn destroy_a(a: *mut c_A) {
    let _a: Box<c_A> = unsafe { Box::from_raw(a) };
}

extern "C" fn create_b(_a: *mut c_A) -> *mut c_B {
    let b = Box::new(c_B {});
    Box::into_raw(b)
}

// Note: While unused here, the argument `_a` is actually used in 
// the C library, so I cannot remove it. (Also, I don't control 
// the C interface)
extern "C" fn destroy_b(_a: *mut c_A, b: *mut c_B) {
    let _b = unsafe { Box::from_raw(b) };
}
```

I have created the following Rusty abstraction over the C functions:

```
struct A {
    a_ptr: *mut c_A,
}

impl A {
    fn new() -> A {
        A { a_ptr: create_a() }
    }
}

impl Drop for A {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        destroy_a(self.a_ptr);
    }
}

struct B<'a> {
    b_ptr: *mut c_B,
    a: &'a A,
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn new(a: &'a A) -> B {
        B {
            b_ptr: create_b(a.a_ptr),
            a,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Drop for B<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        destroy_b(self.a.a_ptr, self.b_ptr);
    }
}
```

The `B` struct contains a reference to `A` for the sole reason that the `a_ptr` is necessary when calling the `destroy_b` function for memory cleanup. This reference is not needed by me for any of my Rust code.

I would now like to create the following struct which references both A and B:

```
struct C<'b> {
    a: A,
    b: B<'b>,
}

impl<'b> C<'b> {
    fn new() -> C<'b> {
        let a = A::new();
        let b = B::new(&a);
        C { a, b }
    }
}

// Main function just so it compiles
fn main() {
    let c = C::new();
}
```

However, this will not compile:

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:76:25
   |
76 |         let b = B::new(&a);
   |                         ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
77 |         C { a, b }
78 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the impl at 73:1...
  --> src/main.rs:73:1
   |
73 | impl<'b> C<'b> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand why this fails: When returning the `C` struct from `C::new()`, it moves the `C`. This means that the `A` contained within is moved, which renders all references to it invalid. Therefore, there's no way I could create that `C` struct. ([Explained in much more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/2364686))

How can I refactor this code in such a way that I can store a `B` in a struct along with its "parent" `A`? There's a few options I've thought of, that won't work:

- Change the C interface: I don't control the C interface, so I can't change it.
- Have `B` store a `*mut c_A` instead of `&A`: If `A` is dropped, then that raw pointer becomes invalid, and will result in undefined behavior when `B` is dropped.
- Have `B` store an owned `A` rather than a reference `&A`: For my use case, I need to be able to create multiple `B`s for each `A`. If `B` owns `A`, then each `A` can only be used to create one `B`.
- Have `A` own all instances of `B`, and only return references to `B` when creating a new `B`: This has the problem that `B`s will accumulate over time until the `A` is dropped, using up more memory than necessary. However, if this is indeed the best way to go about it, I can deal with the slight inconvenience.
- Use the [`rental`](https://crates.io/crates/rental) crate: I would rather take the slight memory usage hit than add the complexity of a new macro to my code. (That is, the complexity of anyone reading my code needing to learn how this macro works)

I suspect that the best solution somehow involves storing at least `A` on the heap so it doesn't need to move around, but I can't figure out how to make this work. Also, I wonder if there is something clever that I can do using raw pointers.

Comment: "so that all of the code [...] easily tested"; links to existing resources showing that you've done research; well-formatted; reasons for rejection of solutions you've found, etc. **Please continue to ask such high-quality questions**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like an ideal case for reference counting. Use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) or [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), depending on your multithreading needs:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct B {
    b_ptr: *mut c_B,
    a: Rc<A>,
}

impl B {
    fn new(a: Rc<A>) -> B {
        B {
            b_ptr: create_b(a.a_ptr),
            a,
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for B {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        destroy_b(self.a.a_ptr, self.b_ptr);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(A::new());
    let x = B::new(a.clone());
    let y = B::new(a);
}
```

- Does not change the C interface.
- `A` cannot be dropped while there are still `B`s referencing it.
- Can create multiple `B`s for each `A`.
- `A`'s memory usage will not increase forever.
- Creates a single heap allocation to store `A` and its reference count.
- `Rc` is in the standard library, no new crate to learn.

---

In the future, you'll be able to use *arbitrary self types* to write this in a nicer manner:

```
#![feature(arbitrary_self_types)]

use std::rc::Rc;

struct A {
    a_ptr: *mut c_A,
}

impl A {
    fn new() -> A {
        A { a_ptr: create_a() }
    }

    fn make_b(self: &Rc<Self>) -> B {
        B {
            b_ptr: create_b(self.a_ptr),
            a: self.clone(),
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for A {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        destroy_a(self.a_ptr);
    }
}

struct B {
    b_ptr: *mut c_B,
    a: Rc<A>,
}

impl Drop for B {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        destroy_b(self.a.a_ptr, self.b_ptr);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(A::new());
    let x = a.make_b();
    let y = a.make_b();
}
```